# Sites css only working in chrome, will not work in ie, firefox or opera

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, opera

I am using cloudflare and have turned dev mode on, then updated the css and it still will not work.

Any ideas?

Site is http://our-gen.com

Comment: What are we comparing against? What is your expected output and what is your code like? Without sufficient information, I'm afraid nobody can help you.

Comment: What would you like me to post, the css or all the pages?

Comment: Just tell us what, specifically, doesn't work? If you could narrow it down to a minimal [sample](http://codepen.io) and add the relevant HTML and CSS here, that would also be nice.

Comment: As far as i can see it's just the css.

Comment: You have a lot of invalid HTML I suggest using the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to understand some of the errors. For example its invalid to have an `<a>` as a child of a `<ul>` or an `<ol>` only a `<li>` is valid.

Comment: No. What *part* of the CSS?

Comment: None of the css works, atleast not in anything but chrome.
Everything works fine in chrome, so idk why it would be a problem in any other browser.
There is nothing that should not work in any other browsers, t should all work in all browsers.

Comment: @user2250755: That isn't really true, but I give up. Fix your HTML as Adrift suggested. `<!DOCTYPE html>` should come before the opening `<html>`, too.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the variety of HTML errors, the reason your stylesheet isn't applying in most browsers is because you have the MIME type wrong:

```
<link href='css/style.css' type='css/text' rel='stylesheet'>
```

It should be `text/css`.

The aforementioned variety of HTML errors includes but is not limited to:

- Invalid list nesting. This:

  ```
  <ul>
  <a href='index.php'>
  <li>
  Home
  </li>
  </a>
  <a href='#catalog.php'>
  <li>
  Catalog
  </li>
  </a>
  <a href='#users.php'>
  <li>
  Users
  </li>
  </a>
  <a href='#forum.php'>
  <li>
  Forum
  </li>
  </a>
  </ul>
  ```

  Ought to look more like this:

  ```
  <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#catalog.php">Catalog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#users.php">Users</a></li>
      <li><a href="#forum.php">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
  ```
- `<!DOCTYPE>` isn't a valid DTD. You probably meant `<!DOCTYPE html>`.
- `<!DOCTYPE html>` should be found at the very beginning of the document, not after `<html>`.

Comment: wow, i feel like a idiot.
thank you so much.